# Почему не срабатывает функция?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Я совсем новичок, написал вот такую программу:

```
bool isEven()
{
    cout << "Enter the number ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    int y = 0;
    y = x % 2;
    if (y == 0) {
        cout << "You number is even" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You number is not even" << endl;
        return false;}
}
int main()
{
bool isEven();
 return 0;}
```

И понять не могу, какого она не работает. Все проверил степпингом. Строчка в main "bool isEven();" попросту игнорируется! Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл у Вашей строчки получился не тот, который Вы думаете.

```
bool even = isEven();
```

или

```
isEven();
```

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что

```
bool isEven();
```

это *объявление функции* (т.е. "где-то есть такая функция - `isEven`, возвращает `bool`").

Чтобы ее вызвать, не надо писать `bool`. Можно вызвать

```
isEven();
```

Можно - если надо ее результат - присвоить его переменной типа `bool`.

И я бы переписал вашу функцию короче:

```
bool isEven() {
    cout << "Enter the number ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    x %= 2;
    cout << "You number is " << (x ? "not " : "") << "even" << endl;
    return x;
    }
```

Хотя на самом деле функция `isEven()` не должна заниматься такими детали, как вводить числа и выводить что-то. Каждая функция должна при хорошем дизайне делать только свой часть работы.

```
bool isEven(int n) { return n%2 == 0; }

int readInt() {
    cout << "Enter the number ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
    }

void print(bool even) {
    cout << "You number is " << (!even ? "not " : "") << "even" << endl;
    }

int main() {
    print(isEven(readInt()));
    }
```